# delete the last column from a csv file in powershell

Tags: csv, powershell-2.0

I am new to powershell. Currently we are in need of a poweshell script to compare two large (100000 rows and n columns (n > 300, also column headers are Dates corresponding to each wednesday). The value of n keeps on incrementing each week in the file. We need to compare the files (current week and last week), and need to make sure that the only difference between the two files is the last column.

I have gone through some Forums and Blogs and I could do only Little due to my ignorance.

If there is a way to drop the last column from a csv file in powershell, we may be able to make use of the below script below to compare the previous week's file and the current week's file after droping the last column from current week's file.

It would be really helpful if someone can help me here with your hard earned knowledge

---

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$file1Array = Get-Content "C:\Risk Management\ref_previous.csv"|Sort-Object
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$file2Array = Get-Content "C:\Risk Management\ref_current.csv"|Sort-Object
$matchingEntries = @()

foreach ($entry in $file1Array) {
    if ($file2Array.Contains($entry)) {
        $matchingEntries += $entry
        } 
    }
foreach ($entry in $matchingEntries){
    $file1Array.Remove($entry)
    $file2Array.Remove($entry)
    }
```

---

Cheers, 
Anil

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the column name you want to exclude is `LastCol` (adjust to your actual column name):

```
$previous = Import-csv "C:\Risk Management\ref_previous.csv" | Select-Object -Property * -ExcludeProperty LastCol | Sort-Object;
$current = Import-csv "C:\Risk Management\ref_current.csv" | Sort-Object;
Compare-Object $previous $current;
```

This will drop the last column from each of the input files and indicate whether the remaining content differs.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. Actually the last column Name varies on a weekly Basis and we are looking for an opton to find the last column Name of the current file in a dynamic manner.

Comment: Also we would Need to remove the last column only from the current file.

Comment: Your second comment has been addressed by an edit. Just remove the `Select-Object`.

Comment: As for the last column name changing weekly, try to get that changed if possible (consistency is best). If that can't be done, I have another idea but can't write it up at the moment.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. One of our Systems is delivering us data on a weekly Basis and this Format with Wednesday date as headers is been used by many different applications in our department. Hence it would be really helpful if we have a generic way to get the last column from a csv file regardless it is blank or not

Comment: Now that I think about it, since you know that the last column is variable but predictable (the previous Wednesday, I presume?), you can calculate that column header right in your script to exclude it.

Comment: thanks for the hint. But this means that we need a manual intervention each time we need to run the script. I would like to have a generic way around to get the last column from a file if it is possible. Sorry about my requirement. I would like to make it as generic as possible

Comment: If the last column is always the previous Wednesday, you can calculate the column name via script & thus make it generic.

Comment: I have tried this way and the script is taking a lot of time to import the csv file and is not working for me. Do you know if there are some other options to compare huge csv files

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer that alroc gave, you should be able to get the last column name using a split operation on the first line of the CSV file, and then using that on the -ExcludeProperty parameter.

However, the Compare-Object command on this doesn't work for me, but it does pull back the right data into each variable.

```
$CurrentFile = "C:\Temp\Current.csv"
$PreviousFile = "C:\Temp\Previous.csv"

$CurrentHeaders = gc $CurrentFile | Select -First 1
$CurrentHeadersSplit = $CurrentHeaders.Split(",")
$LastColumn = $CurrentHeadersSplit[-1] -Replace '"'

$Current = Import-Csv $CurrentFile | Select -Property * -ExcludeProperty $LastColumn | Sort-Object
$Previous = Import-Csv $PreviousFile | Sort-Object
Compare-Object $Current $Previous
```

Answer (score 0):

The import-csv and export-csv both give the opportunity to exclude columns.

The import-csv has the -header option and you simply name the incoming headers and exclude the last columns header.  If there are 10 columns, only name 9. The last column will be excluded.

For export-csv, select the columns you'd like to write out ( |select col1,col2,col3|export-csv... ) and don't select the column you're trying to exclude.

Comment: Hi Mr.Jenkins, Thank you for the response. But there are around 300 columns and it is difficult to list it for the user